# Dictionary changing key value Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have got a dictionary in the form of:

```
{0.1: (0.7298579,0.7987254)}
```

which corresponds to: `{test_size: (train_error, test_error)}`.

I would like to change the key value `test_size` into `1 - test_size`. So that we obtain:

```
{0.9: (0.7298579, 0.7987254)}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try with the `.pop()` method of dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this :

```
>>> d = {0.1:(0.7298579,0.7987254)}
>>> new_d = {1-k: v for k, v in d.items()}
>>> new_d
{0.9: (0.7298579, 0.7987254)}
```

Answer (score -2):

If the dict is not horribly huge, you can just create a new dict and copy the old one with new keys.